# how can I get the topmost view at any time in iphone sdk4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can I get the topmost view at any time in iphone sdk4?

Answer (score 3):

it would be helpful if you ask your question a bit more in detail, but anyway you can try it with this line of code:

```
UIView *topMostView = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews.firstObject;
```

cheers,
anka

Comment: Thanks Anka. I am sure this will be useful at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answer to another thread here. Problem of returning UIKeyBoard object was because; while it was a UIView in older SDK, it is UIWindow in iphone SDK 4. Problem solved.